# Last insert id return error in Yii

Tags: postgresql, yii

I just executed some code in controller, and try to find the last inserted id.

But it display s error :

This is my code:

```
$sql = 'INSERT into "Tbl_Community" ("User_id","Community_name") VALUES (10,'new community')';
$connection = Yii::app() -> db;
$command = $connection -> createCommand($sql);
$command -> execute();
echo $connection->getLastInsertID();
```

The error:

```
[message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42602]: Invalid name: 7 ERROR:  invalid name syntax
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 42602
    [file:protected] => D:\wamp\www\Tiein\framework\db\CDbConnection.php
    [line:protected] => 548
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\wamp\www\Tiein\framework\db\CDbConnection.php
                    [line] => 548
                    [function] => lastInsertId
                    [class] => PDO
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )
```

Answer (score 5):

with postgresql you can't get last by this way

```
$lastId= Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

try this (tbl_user_group_id is your table id column and _seq is for postgresql)

```
$lastId = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID('tbl_user_group_id_seq');
```

**OR**

```
$lastId= Yii::app()->db->getCommandBuilder()->getLastInsertID('{{tablename}}') ;
```

Comment: Ok, Best of Luck @YoussefEssayesy, by the way you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what user714965 pointed out, I usually put the parameters in execute just to make sure they are used properly by PDO. If you write SQL command like in your example and you read the parameters from a form it is problematic.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('INSERT into "Tbl_Community" ("User_id","Community_name") VALUES (:User_id,:Community_name)')->execute(array(":User_id"=>10, ":Community_name"=>"new community"));
$id = Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();
```

Comment: the insertion to the table is done, but last inserted id not accessable

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution :

```
$sql = 'INSERT into "Tbl_Community" ("User_id","Community_name") VALUES (10,\'new community\')';
    $connection = Yii::app() -> db;
    $command = $connection -> createCommand($sql);
    $command -> execute();
    $id = $connection->getCommandBuilder()->getLastInsertID('{{Tbl_Community}}');
echo $id;
```

PDO::lastInsertID() requires the name parameter when used with PDO_PGSQL so need to replace this code `Yiii::app()->db->getLastInsertID();` by `Yii::app()->db->getCommandBuilder()->getLastInsertID('{{tablename}}') ;`

Refer this [link](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/pull/45)

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late to reply to this thread. But here is the case.

- As Per the user 'Always Sunny' you can send the 'Sequence Name' by hardcoding, but that's not a good coding practice.
- As per the user 'Kitchu' the use of 'getCommandBuilder' is good, because, provided the 'TableName', it will query the Schema and finds out the 'Sequence Name'. It will inturn query the CDBCommand's 'getLastInsertId' by passing the 'Sequence Name'

One thing to ensure that it, if you have not defined the 'Primary Key' on the table, then you will end up getting the value as 'NULL'